# Problem in adding releated field to serializer

Tags: python, django, django-serializer

I have two classes which are `Land` and `UTMPoint`:

```
class UTMPoint(models.Model):
    x = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    y = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    z = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    land = models.ForeignKey('Land', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

And their serializers are:

```
class UTMPointsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = UTMPoint
    fields = ('id', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'land',)
    read_only_fields = ('id',)


class LandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

user = UserSerializer()
utm_points = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
class Meta:
    model = Land
    fields = ('id', 'user', 'activity_field','activity_location',
        'area', 'part', 'location','verification_code', 'verified', 
        'description', 'approved', 'receipt_bank_name', 'receipt_serial', 
        'receipt_date', 'receipt_amount','utm_points',)
    read_only_fields = ('id', 'approved',)

def create(self, validated_data):        
    user = validated_data.pop('user')
    user = User.objects.create(**user)
    user.save()

    land = Land.objects.create(user=user,**validated_data)
    land.save()
    return land
```

As you see `Land` has `utm_points` releated field but when I run this test:

```
def test_create_land(self):
    """test creating land"""
    payload = {
        'activity_field': 'farming',
        'user': {'national_code': '12333', 'password': 'passW@rd'},
        'activity_location': 'Kermanshah',
        'area': 'sw',
        'part': 'sp', 
        'location': 'the old address',
        'verification_code': '1',
        'verified': '0', 
        'description': 'sb is calling for it', 
        'approved': True, 
        'receipt_bank_name': 'meili',
        'receipt_serial': '12312',
        'receipt_amount': '10000',
    }
    res = self.client.post(LAND_URL, payload, format='json')

    self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I get this error `AttributeError: 'Land' object has no attribute 'utm_points'`

I have no idea why this error is throwing `Land` has properly the related field `utm_points` so why it happes?

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to add `related_name` in `UTM_Point` model's `land` field:

```
class UTMPoint(models.Model):
    x = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    y = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    z = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    land = models.ForeignKey('Land', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='utm_points'). # <-- Here
```

For more information, please see the [documentation on `related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).